# Is there a community-specific bug report feature?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

The VTC reason "This question belongs on another SE site" doesn't work right.  Currently, after selecting that option, the only Stack you can choose is WB.meta.  I highly doubt that is intended.

Where can I report this bug?

Comment: I ran into the same problem when I started using Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, that particular VTC path is 100% controlled by Stack Exchange, not any individual Stack, and SE is notorious for not following through on obvious enhancements. So, it's easier to think, "if I want to migrate a question to Meta, use 'This Q belongs on another SE site,' and if you actually want it on another Stack, use 'Other - add a comment.'"

Comment: BTW, officially, when you post to Meta with the [tag:bug] tag, Stack Exchange's bug tracker automatically picks it up and reports it. But like I said, given that SE is notorious for not following through on bugs and enhancement requests....

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug.

It is meant as a moderator only feature, as pointed out [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2811/30492)

And also a more thorough reasoning is posted [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4530/30492)

Answer (score 1):

You already have; the "bug-report feature" is called Meta.